# trying to access json data but getting a crossorigin request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to access the following data with the following jquery ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/data/hipstercoffee',
success: function(data) {
  console.log('success', data);
}

});
```

When I run the function it is not able to load the file. The error I am getting is "failed to load the file and cross origin request are only supported ....."
The json data is formatted as follows.

```
[
{
"shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
"address": "123 Lakeside Way",
"phone": "16503600708",
"prices": [
  {
    "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
    "Flat White": 4.75,
    "Cappucino": 3.85,
    "Single Espresso": 2.05,
    "Double Espresso": 3.75,
    "Americano": 3.75,
    "Cortado": 4.55,
    "Tea": 3.65,
    "Choc Mudcake": 6.40,
    "Choc Mousse": 8.20,
    "Affogato": 14.80,
    "Tiramisu": 11.40,
    "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
    "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
    "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
  }
]
}
]
```

Will this function work with this kind of formatted json file?

Comment: Cross-Origin means that the request is not coming from the same server the data is on, although according to the JS you posted, it looks like it should be. If it truly isn't, you can configure the server to accept it (lookup CORS) but it may need some work. If it is, your code doesn't show any reason why it should give you such an error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.  I should have been running a MAMP server.  Plus, the url is incorrect. It should be

```
url: '/data/hipstercoffee.json',
```